# How do I fetch events based on timestamp and show the result on a calender in flutter firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

Using this flutter package [flutter_table_calender](https://pub.dev/packages/table_calendar) which have the property of `Events` that takes and array as list of date.

I have array of date in firebase, but the problem is , the array in firebase saves the date as `Timestamp`  Although I know how to convert a `TimeStamp` to `DateTime` in flutter but I am unable to convert an array of `timeStamp` to an array to `DateTime`.

Answer (score 1):

I am not clear what you want. But if you want to convert **Timestamp** type(Firestore Date) to **DateTime** type, use code as follows:

You should use **fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch** function.

```
var d = new DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(ts, isUtc: true);
```

Here ts is int type.

So we can convert Firebase **timestamps** to DateTime object as follows.

```
DateTime date = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(timestamp.seconds * 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what I was lookign for is not this but this will be of some use .

Comment: Tell me what you want. And then I will give you a good answer.

Comment: what i want is , there will be a calender and when the user taps on a particular date then it will fetch event associated with that date from firebase which is saved as an array in firebase.

Comment: I want to help you. So I want to know in details. Contact me using Skype. My skype id: live:.cid.1a3f7a80fa264ca1